# Convert literal string to list inside python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
helpful
'[2, 4]'
'[0, 0]'
'[0, 1]'
'[7, 13]'
'[4, 6]'
```

Column name helpful has a list inside the string. I want to split 2 and 4 into separate columns.

```
[int(each) for each in df['helpful'][0].strip('[]').split(',')]
```

This works the first row but if I do

```
[int(each) for each in df['helpful'].strip('[]').split(',')]
```

gives me attribute error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

How can I print out like this in my dataframe??

```
helpful not_helpful
2       4
0       0
0       1
7       13
4       6
```

Comment: Look at `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: The first question is how you're _getting_ those strings with lists inside. If you're trying to store data by just printing it out to a file as strings and then parsing the result, that's almost never a good idea—see `json`, `pickle`, and various alternatives you can find on PyPI—but in the specific case of a CSV, why not make it two columns instead of one column with a 2-element list? Or a Numpy struct field, or a Pandas compound thingy I forget the name of?

Comment: json file that I found online had a list of the string in one column. My goal is to split it and make it into two separate columns. Thank you for your feedback tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @abarnert, the first port of call is find out *why* your data is coming across as strings and try and rectify that problem.

However, if this is beyond your control, you can use `ast.literal_eval` as below.

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.DataFrame({'helpful': ['[2, 4]', '[0, 0]', '[0, 1]', '[7, 13]', '[4, 6]']})

res = pd.DataFrame(df['helpful'].map(literal_eval).tolist(),
                   columns=['helpful', 'not_helpful'])

#    helpful  not_helpful
# 0        2            4
# 1        0            0
# 2        0            1
# 3        7           13
# 4        4            6
```

**Explanation**

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), `ast.literal_eval` performs the following function:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
>   consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you've described here accurately mimics your real-world case, how about a regex with [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)?

```
>>> regex = r'\[(?P<helpful>\d+),\s*(?P<not_helpful>\d+)\]'
>>> df
  helpful
0  [2, 4]
1  [0, 0]
2  [0, 1]

>>> df['helpful'].str.extract(regex, expand=True).astype(np.int64)
   helpful  not_helpful
0        2            4
1        0            0
2        0            1
```

Each pattern `(?P<name>...)` is a named capturing group.  Here, there are two: helpful/not helpful.  This assumes the pattern can be described by: opening bracket, 1 or more digits, comma, 0 or more spaces, 1 or more digits, and closing bracket.  The Pandas method (`.extract()`), as its name implies, "extracts" the result of `match.group(i)` for each `i`:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = r'\[(?P<helpful>\d+),\s*(?P<not_helpful>\d+)\]'
>>> re.search(regex, '[2, 4]').group('helpful')
'2'
>>> re.search(regex, '[2, 4]').group('not_helpful')
'4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun without module.

```
s = """
helpful
'[2, 4]'
'[0, 0]'
'[0, 1]'
'[7, 13]'
'[4, 6]'
"""

lst = s.strip().splitlines()
d = {'helpful':[], 'not_helpful':[]}

el = [tuple(int(x) for x in e.strip("'[]").split(', ')) for e in lst[1:]]

d['helpful'].extend(x[0] for x in el)
d['not_helpful'].extend(x[1] for x in el)

NUM_WIDTH = 4
COLUMN_WIDTH = max(len(k) for k in d)
print('{:^{num_width}}{:^{column_width}}{:^{column_width}}'.format(
    ' ', *sorted(d),
    num_width=NUM_WIDTH,
    column_width=COLUMN_WIDTH
    )
)
for (i, v) in enumerate(zip(d['helpful'], d['not_helpful']), 1):
    print('{:^{num_width}}{:^{column_width}}{:^{column_width}}'.format(
        i, *v,
        num_width=NUM_WIDTH,
        column_width=COLUMN_WIDTH
        )
    )
```